# Get screen size similar to CursorPos (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, cursor-position

Using the User32 Lib and the functions:

```
Public Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "User32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Public Type POINTAPI
x As Long
y As Long
End Type
Public pos As POINTAPI
```

You can see the pixel location of the cursor with:

```
GetCursorPos pos
Debug.Print("X: " & pos.x & " Y: " & pos.y)
```

My question is, is it possible to see the screen size using the same method as the GetCursorPos? My reason being that dual monitors can cause that function to return negative values. For example, one setup may be this between two monitors on the left/right:

```
'Not sure if true or not
MinX: -1920
MaxX: 1920
MinY: -1080
MaxY: 1080
```

I'm basically asking how to use something similar to GetCursorPos, but to retrieve the borders of the screens.

Comment: the pos comes from the "first" screen (top left corner)... if the second is over or left from it you will get negative numbers...

Comment: but to get the resolution you need something like `Declare PtrSafe Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "User32" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long` and then get with `GetSystemMetrics(0)`  and `GetSystemMetrics(1)` the size of the first monitor while having `GetSystemMetrics(78)` and `GetSystemMetrics(79)` holding the sum of both (if they are left/right you get the sum of x and the higher y)

Comment: @DirkReichel thanks for the GetSystemMetrics(78) and (79)! That may be what I need. I don't suppose you know how to figure out the monitor setup through VBA do you (primary on left/right or top/bottom)?.

Comment: there lots of guides always refering to the same VB script which I am not able to make it work (all I ever reached was crashing excel)... 78/79 just gives the max ranges (while 0/1 gets you to the primary)... youd need to calculate to get the pos and size of the second screen... but that's more like guessing :/ maybe you are able to adopt [THIS](http://www.developerfusion.com/thread/49351/vb-dual-screen/) to VBA (as said, I wasn't able to)

Answer (score 0):

You can access WMI through VBA and for getting system configuration data then, personally, I think that this is less esoteric and less unstable than coding against the Win32 APIs. WMI classes are better documented in MSDN and once you learn the technique to talk to one class, you can access the whole range of system information that is exposed.

Here's an example of the querying the [Win32_DesktopMonitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122(v=vs.85).aspx) class:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetMonitorInfo()

    'WMI query
    Dim objWmiInterface As Object
    Dim objWmiQuery As Object
    Dim objWmiQueryItem As Object
    Dim strWQL As String
    'outputs
    Dim strDeviceId As String
    Dim strScreenName As String
    Dim varScreenHeight As Variant
    Dim varScreenWidth As Variant

    'run query
    strWQL = "Select * From Win32_DesktopMonitor"
    Set objWmiInterface = GetObject("winmgmts:root/CIMV2")
    Set objWmiQuery = objWmiInterface.ExecQuery(strWQL)
    'iterate output
    For Each objWmiQueryItem In objWmiQuery
        strDeviceId = objWmiQueryItem.DeviceId
        strScreenName = objWmiQueryItem.Name
        varScreenHeight = objWmiQueryItem.ScreenHeight
        varScreenWidth = objWmiQueryItem.ScreenWidth
        Debug.Print strDeviceId
        Debug.Print strScreenName
        Debug.Print varScreenHeight
        Debug.Print varScreenWidth
        Debug.Print ""
    Next

End Sub
```

In my case, I have a laptop with dual monitors attached. The laptop lid is closed so I guess that is why `ScreenHeight` and `ScreenWidth` are `Null` for the first item:

```
DesktopMonitor1
Default Monitor
Null
Null

DesktopMonitor2
Default Monitor
 1080 
 1920 

DesktopMonitor3
Generic PnP Monitor
 1080 
 1920
```

Comment: I have a laptop with the lip open and an external monitor. This code only detected DesktopMonoitor1, Generic PnP Monitor, Null, Null.